# Check if output from grep is empty before sending email from Crontab

Tags: bash, email, grep, cron

I have the following entry in my Crontab which will `grep` my logs for any instance of error, warning, notice etc...

`41 17 * * * cd /var/log/crmpicco-logs/; grep -E "error|Warning|Error|Notice|Fatal" $(find . -mtime 0 -type f) 2>&1 | mail -s "Errors/Warnings from Logs" info@ayrshireminis.com`

What I would like to do is tweak it so that it only executes the `mail` command if the output from the `grep` search returns a result. So, if it's empty then I don't want to receive an email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it conditional:

> `41 17 * * * cd /var/log/crmpicco-logs/; s=$(find . -mtime 0 -exec grep -E "error|Warning|Error|Notice|Fatal" {} +); [[ -n "$s" ]] && echo "$s" | mail -s "Errors/Warnings from Logs" info@ayrshireminis.com`

Comment: You have a double `grep` there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are satisfied with a little less, `cron` itself can do most of what you want.

```
MAILTO=info@ayrshireminis.com
41 17 * * * find /var/log/crmpicco-logs/ -mtime 0 -type f -exec grep -E "[Ee]rror|Warning|Notice|Fatal" {} +
```

If there is no output, there will be no email, either.

(Refactored mainly for stylistic reasons.)

Comment: Nice suggestion, although this would affect every cron job in my crontab if I set `MAILTO` at the top.

Comment: So don't set it at the top.

Answer (score 0):

From `man mail`:

> ```
>    -E     If  an  outgoing message does not contain any text in its first or only message part, do not send it but discard it silently, effectively setting the skipemptybody variable at program startup.  This is useful for sending messages
>           from scripts started by cron(8).
> ```

So, i think, it is possible just to add `-E` key to command:

```
41 17 * * * cd /var/log/crmpicco-logs/; grep -E "error|Warning|Error|Notice|Fatal" $(find . -mtime 0 -type f) 2>&1 | mail -E -s "Errors/Warnings from Logs" info@ayrshireminis.com
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if egrep -q "error|Warning|Error|Notice|Fatal" $(find . -mtime 0 -type f;then 
egrep "error|Warning|Error|Notice|Fatal" $(find . -mtime 0 -type f)|mail -s "Errors/Warnings from Logs" info@ayrshireminis.com
fi
```

The above codes `grep -E` with egrep (the same thing)

conditional test with egrep with a -q option to supress output, once test is true then executes command without suppressing output

Comment: You have massive code duplication and a (simple, but still) syntax error.